# How much cash is in the wallet

Tags: combinatorics

In the wallet we have $26$ banknotes. If we take, arbitrarily, $20$ of them we are sure that we have at least one of $\$5$, at least two of $\$10$ and at least five of $\$20$. How much cash is in the wallet?

I have tried determining the number of compositions of $20$ in three parts with regard to the restrictions. Also tried using normal generating functions and obtaining coefficient next to $x^{20}$, but I don't see where does that get me. Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: Are 5, 10 and 20 the only types of banknotes in the wallet?

Comment: It is not stated, but I believe they are. Otherwise it would be horrible, I assume

Comment: Consider 20\$ first. There is $N$ banknotes 20\$ and $26-N$ other banknotes. What can/must $N$ be to have at least five 20\$ banknotes in any 20 drawn?

Comment: I am ashamed to admit that, although I see that $11 = 6 + 5$, where 6 is how much we have left when I 26\choose20 and 5 that are guaranteed, and same for 1+6 and 2+6, I still don't understand it. I get this, but I don't see how is that all connected. Can anyone explain it, further. I am ashamed that I can't solve a Elementary school problem...

Comment: I see it now. Tis was painful experience... And shameful too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is much simpler. If we take 20 of the 26 notes, and we have at least five $\$20$ notes, then there must be at least eleven $ \$20$ notes (since otherwise the guarantee does not work). For similar reasons, there must be at least seven $ \$5$ notes, and at least eight $ \$10$ notes. Because $11+7+8 = 26$, this is all the notes in the wallet, and the total amount of cash is $\$(7\times 5 + 8 \times 10 + 11 \times 20)$.